# standard action 'New' and 'Edit' override with single aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning-action-override

I am trying to override two standard actions New and Edit for my custom object through a single Aura component. I am not sure how to find inside my aura which button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `recordId` is null, it is a new record, otherwise `recordId` will be the Id of the record you're editing.